# Rationale behind methods that convert values

Tags: java

What is the purpose of having methods converting one value into another value of a different type. For example a method that converts a string of digits into an int and another method converting an int into a string of digits? What exactly would be the advantages to doing one over the other? Is it there is no advantage and the methods for conversion exist only to provide compatible values for the arguments of the constructors of different classes?

Comment: Have you tried adding strings of digits together? It's a bit different than adding actual integers...

Comment: It sounds like you're basically asking why Java is strongly typed. Do you come from a PHP background or something?

Comment: @Antimony java is my first language.

Comment: @Jessica personally I find java's "tell me exactly what you want to do" a **lot** nicer than some other languages that guess what you want. But try some others and see what you prefer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply, it's because those different types exhibit different behaviors:

```
String str = "42";

System.out.println(str + 1);
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(str) + 1);
```

```
421
43
```

You need to have methods like `Integer.parseInt()` if you want to perform normal addition as opposed to string concatenation, for example.

A tangible example of this can come up when you read a number as input from a user; more often than not you will want to treat this number as a *number* (`double`, `int`, etc.) as opposed to a string.

Comment: @andy256 why is 42 special?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=answer+to+life%2C+the+universe%2C+and+everything

Comment: @Jessica Not a hitchhikers guide to the galaxy fan I take it

Comment: @JessicaM. As NutterzUK's link says, 42 is the answer to "Life, the Universe, and Everything". But as Slartibartfast says "It's not important" :-)

Answer (score 4):

The different forms serve different purposes beyond providing compatible values for methods and constructors.

For the `int` type, mathematical operations are most easily performed on this type (and similar primitive types).  User input is usually given in the form of a `String`, so to perform a mathematical operation on user input, one must convert it into an `int` (or a `double`, `long`, `float`, `byte`, or `short` as appropriate).

For converting to a `String`: This is how numerical output is displayed.  We may code `System.out.println(myInt);`, but behind the scenes, Java is converting the number to a `String` for display purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Since you used the "Java" tag, I'll answer you regarding java.

**It is because, Java was written this way** . There are languages that do not need types (lisp for example) and you can read a string (from Std. In) and raise it to a power (for example) if it is a number. But Java needs types. The compiler wants to know it ahead.

One useful advantage of being able to convert numbers to string is that you are able to use very large numbers, storing them as strings, instead of integers. However you cannot work with strings when you use the regular operators (+,-,*,/).

Another advantage: when you have a TextField and you read user input, it is given as a string. So you need to get a number out of it to work with it.